# Google AdMob is not working with Android application

Tags: android, cordova, admob, cordova-plugins

I need to show ads on my android application.So I am using google admob plugin for showing ads in my application. After building the apk file it is showing an error admob undefined. Please any one tell, why am I getting this error? and suggest solutions. I am using Cordova for building android apk.

I am using cordova version 1.3.6,
sdk android20,
plugin-"com.google.cordova.admob","com.google.play.services","com.ios.libgoogleadmobads"

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of com.google.play.services and com.ios.libgoogleadmobads. Those libraries are prepared to work with the plugin com.admob.google: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova

Are you testing in a real device/emulator? Normally those plugins don't support browser simulators.

Answer (score 0):

To use AdMob, no need to add so many plugins, cause they may cause conflict with each other. Only "com.google.cordova.admob" willl work.

See the doc and sample code here:
https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/tree/regio